# How do address angular display issue on IE 10

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

Ok, this will be a challenging question b/c I can't display code examples since I'm not sure where the issue even is.

I'm experiencing a client side bug displaying data in IE 10 that is rendered by angularJS. What happens is the browser displays old data on the UI and angularJS updates it after making a call to the db.

What's happening is after the new data is fetched, the old data is cleared, but not displayed leaving a blank screen. But, if the browser window is re-sized or there's some other UI activity like tabbing from one field to another, the new data becomes visible.

What makes this even more weird is that it happens only on IE 10.0.9200.17414
and only on some customer accounts, not all.

Also, if I'm in IE 11 it works. If I'm in IE 11 & emulate 10, it still works fine.

Again, if I re-size the window a little or had UI activity on the browser like tabbing one field to another, the angular data is triggered to display.

Does anyone know what I can do in Angular to prevent this from happening? To make sure returned angular data is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the version of Angular from 1.0.8 to 1.2.0 did the trick.